# MVC Entity Framework Count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to build a result like: **CategoryID || Count(Searches) || CategoryName** based on two Entity Framework based classes:

```
public class Category
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SearchPreviewControllerAction { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SearchTitle { get; set; }
    public string SearchStandard { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I already made a SearchPreview method that returns the Searches based on a search like "Aston Martin" that will find in all categories with the words "Aston Martin".

The challenge now is to build a method that returns, after the Search of the keywords "Aston Martin", in which categories there are those keywords including the count, like "Auto: 2 | Seeling point: 3 | Shop: 2"

I am trying to avoid a query for each category to count the number of Searches entry, and I would like to find a *GroupBy* solution, that takes the SearchPreview method already executed and extract the *GroupBy* Categories that it contains.

I am using the ViewModel `SearchPreviewListCategoriesViewModel` to map from the models using Automapper:

```
public class SearchPreviewListCategoriesViewModel
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SearchPreviewControllerAction { get; set; }
    public int SearchCount { get; set; }
}
```

Hope somoeone can help me on this.

Thank you.

Regards,

Patrick.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I discover DTO's maybe it's the solution, but I'm still investigating. When I found an answer, what I have to do? Put the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found to the problem:

Step 1:

Creation of a Data Transfer Object to take the Domain object and deliver it to the Presentation Web Layer:

```
public class SearchCategoriesListDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SearchPreviewControllerAction { get; set; }
    public int SearchCount { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2:

Refacturing of the mapping between the DTO and the ViewModel in the Presentation Layer:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SearchCategoriesListDto, SearchCategoriesListViewModel>();
```

Step 3:

Method to deliver the CategoryName, the Count by Category and the ControllerAction Name that will deliver the list for each Category list:

```
    public IList<SearchCategoriesListDto> SearchPreviewCategories(String keywords)
    {

        string keywordsClean = keywords;

        keywordsClean = keywordsClean.ToUpper();
        keywordsClean = StringUtils.StringSimbolsRemove(keywordsClean, HeelpResources.StringSymbolsToCleanFrom, HeelpResources.StringSymbolsToCleanTo);

        string[] splitKeywords = keywordsClean.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

        var searchQuery = _searchRepository.Query;

        foreach (string keyword in splitKeywords)
        {
            searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(p => p.SearchStandard.Contains(keyword));
        }

        var categoryQuery = _categoryRepository.Query;

        var query = from sq in searchQuery
                    join cq in categoryQuery on sq.CategoryId equals cq.Id
                    select new SearchCategoriesListDto { 
                        Name = cq.Name, 
                        SearchCount = searchQuery.Where(c => c.CategoryId == cq.Id).Count(), 
                        SearchPreviewControllerAction = cq.SearchPreviewControllerAction 
                    };

        var searchResults = query.Distinct().ToList();

        return searchResults;
```

}

Thanks for all the help I got from StackOverlow to solve this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're matching, but maybe something like this

```
from c in aCategories where c.Search.Any(s => s.SearchStandard.Contains("Aston Martin") == true) select new SearchPreviewListCategoriesViewModel { CategoryID = c.Id, Name = c.Name, SearchPreviewControllerAction = c.SearchPreviewControllerAction, SearchCount = (c.Search.Where(s => s.SearchStandard.Contains("Aston Martin") == true)).Count() };
```

where aCategories is your context access to the Category table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is also that at the CategoryService level the method return IList<Category> and not the ViewModel SearchCategoriesListViewModel, this match is done using AutoMapper at Controller level, so how I include the Count in the middle of the IList<Category> return?

Comment: Not sure I get what you're saying, but if you want a list of results from your query to look like:

    Category1 instance, # of search hits in 1
    Category2 instance, # of search hits in 2
    ...

then it's what I proposed, except you simply

    ... select new { Category = c, SearchCount = (c.Search.Where(s => s.SearchStandard.Contains("Aston Martin") == true)).Count() };

and iterate over the dynamically typed Category SearchCount pairs.

Comment: The return type IList<Category> of the Category Service method SearchCategories don't have a property "Count" that allows me to store the search count and return the result to the modelView

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with AutoMapper project.  If you can return the IList<Category> and a pairing of the CategoryId + search counts from the query above, you may be able to aggregate them together in your view: One query to get list of Category, one query to get list of counts, then logic to match in your view.

Comment: Yes but the number of iterations to the database for each count is heavy, and I already have the count in the search result because each search result has the categoryId in it. Maybe using DTO in the service layer to return to the Presentation Layer?

Comment: Not sure about DTO, but I'm not suggesting hitting the db to get the count for each unique category in the IList result.  I'm suggesting you run just 2 queries: the first to get the IList of categories, the second to get the same category results, but with a count of hits for each as well.  After running the 2 queries, you stitch the counts back to the corresponding category wherever you want.

Comment: thanks, I have been researching for DTO's maybe it's the answer for my problem